# Haar measure on a compact group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group and $\mu$ a Haar measure on $G$. Let $A \subset G$. Is it true that $\mu(A) = \mu(A^{-1})$? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Define $\nu(E) = \mu(Ex)$ (for fixed $x\in G$).

It is easy to see that $\nu$ is a Haar measure on $G$ with $\nu(G) = \mu(G)$, so that $\nu =\mu$ by uniqueness. This shows that $\mu$ is also right invariant.

Now define $\gamma(E) = \mu(E^{-1})$. By right invariance of $\mu$, $\gamma$ is left invariant with $\gamma(G) = \mu(G)$. By uniqueness, we see $\gamma = \mu$, completing the proof.

EDIT: Compactess is used here to deduce $\mu(G) <\infty$, so that the argument $\mu(G) = \nu(G)$ (and similar for $\gamma$) indeed implies $\mu =\nu$ (because uniqueness only yields $\nu = c \mu$ for some $c>0$).