# How to show that $\int_G f(t) dt = \int_G f(t^{-1}) dt$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

I am reading [the lecture notes](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sharmonics.pdf). On page 34, line 13, it is said that $\int_G f(t) dt = \int_G f(t^{-1}) dt$. How to prove this identity? I think that if we let $s=t^{-1}$, then $\int_Gf(t^{-1})dt=\int_{G^{-1}}f(s)d(s^{-1}) = \int_G f(s)\frac{-1}{s^2}ds$. But I didn't get $\int_G f(t) dt = \int_G f(t^{-1}) dt$. Thank you very much.

Comment: $\text{d}t$ represents the Haar measure on $G$.  For example, if $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$, then $\text{d}t$ is the usual Lebesgue measure and you can see that $\text{d}(-t)=\text{d}t$, whence $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\,f(-t)\,\text{d}t=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\,f(t)\,\text{d}t$.  If $G=\left(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\cdot\right)$, then $\text{d}t$ is $\frac{\text{d}\lambda(t)}{t}$, where $\lambda$ is the usual Lebesgue measure, so that $$\text{d}t^{-1}=\frac{\text{d}\lambda\left(t^{-1}\right)}{t^{-1}}=\frac{t^{-2} \, \text{d}\lambda(t)}{t^{-1}}=\frac{\text{d}\lambda(t)}{t}=\text{d}t\,.$$

Comment: In general, if $\text{d}t$ is a Haar measure on $G$, it must satisfy $\text{d}t^{-1}=\text{d}t$ (or one is a nonzero scalar multiple of the other).  By Haar measures, I mean that they must be both left- and right-invariant.  And if a group $G$ has a Haar measure, it is called *unimodular*, which your text mentions.

Comment: @Batominovski, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the main thread and FelxCQ's answer, the lecture notes state that $t$ is a right invariant Haar measure on a compact Lie group $G$.  It is demonstrated in [Haar measure on a compact group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956750/haar-measure-on-a-compact-group/956759#956759) that for any subset $A$ of $G$:
$$t(A) = t(A^{-1})$$

(Note that your the notes also specify that $t$ has been normalized, i.e.
$\int_G dt = 1$)

where $A$ is the set of inverses of group elements.  i.e. $t$ is invariant under the inverse operation.

Now $$\int_G f(t^{-1}) dt = \int_{G^{-1}} f(t) dt^{-1} = \int_G f(t) dt$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe this notation denotes the group inverse, not the real involution function.

I don't know how to prove this, but intuitively, as $g$ describes the whole group $G$, $g^{-1}$ also describes $G$ "at the same rate", so both integrals should be equal.

Comment: Although I agree with your first statement, I believe the second one needs more work.  There is a change of variables that needs to be performed which will induce a modification to the volume form $dt$.  However, in the notes, it is stated that $t$ is Left and Right invariant Haar measure.

Comment: @muaddib, you're right, I clarified that this was just my intuition, not a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Because G is compact, so is unimodular. Therefore Haar modulus of G is constant function 1. So the equality is clear.